# Matrix Multiplication in C with input from a file

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication

I've written a program for matrix multiplication but I want to modify it. Firstly, I want to change matrices to first[a][b] instead of 10 and read the dimensions of matrix from file .Would I need to allocate memory dynamically depending on dimensions of matrix using malloc or I can take some maximum, but that would lead to wastage of lot of memory Would I need to store dimensions of matrix in an array from a file. Suggest what changes do I need ? I am not opening file , just redirecting stdin to file. I am unable to get the input via file ??

Modified code is as

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
 int m, n, p, q, c, d, k, sum = 0;
  int **first, **second, **multiply;
  printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of first matrix\n");
  scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
  first = malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
   for (int i =0;i <m; i++)
first[i] =malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    second = malloc(p*sizeof(int*));
     for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
second[i] = malloc(q*sizeof(int));
multiply = malloc(m*sizeof(int));
for (int i=0;i<q;i++)
multiply[i] = malloc(q*sizeof(int));
printf("Enter the elements of first matrix\n");
    for (  c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
    for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
      scanf("%d", &first[c][d]);
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of second matrix\n");
  scanf("%d%d", &p, &q);
  if ( n != p )
    printf(
  "Matrices with entered orders can't be multiplied with each other.\n");
  else {
 printf("Enter the elements of second matrix\n");
 for ( c = 0 ; c < p ; c++ )
  for ( d = 0 ; d < q ; d++ )
    scanf("%d", &second[c][d]);
 for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ ) {
  for ( d = 0 ; d < q ; d++ ) {
    for ( k = 0 ; k < p ; k++ ) {
      sum = sum + first[c][k]*second[k][d];
    }
    multiply[c][d] = sum;
    sum = 0;
  }
  }
 printf("Product of entered matrices:-\n");
 for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ ) {
  for ( d = 0 ; d < q ; d++ )
    printf("%d\t", multiply[c][d]);
  printf("\n");
 }
for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
  free(second[i]);
free(second);
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
  free(multiply[i]);
  free(multiply);
}
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
free(first[i]);
 free(first);
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Do not vandalize your question to the extent that the answers are meaningless.  People worked to aid you; you may not render that aid pointless.

Answer (score 4):

**Change declarations:**

```
int i, m, n, p, q, c, d, k, sum = 0;
int **first, **second, **multiply;
```

**After `scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);`:**

```
first = malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
  first[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

**Before `printf("Enter the elements of second matrix\n");`:**

```
second = malloc(p*sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
  second[i] = malloc(q*sizeof(int));

multiply = malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < q; i++)
  multiply[i] = malloc(q*sizeof(int));
```

**Free statements:** (at the end of the program) (**always** required if the program **doesn't** exit right after)

Replace:

```
  }
  return 0;
}
```

with:

```
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
      free(second[i]);
    free(second);
    for (i = 0; i < q; i++)
      free(multiply[i]);
    free(multiply);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    free(first[i]);
  free(first);
  return 0;
}
```

**An alternative approach:** Assign a sequential block of memory

Declarations:

```
int *first, *second, *multiply;
```

`malloc`'s: (no for-loops)

- `first = malloc(m*n*sizeof(int));`
- `second = malloc(p*q*sizeof(int));`
- `multiply = malloc(m*q*sizeof(int));`

Usage:

- Change `first[c][k]` to `first[c*m+k]`
- Change `second[k][d]` to `second[k*p+d]`
- Change `multiply[c][d]` to `first[c*m+d]`

`free`'s: (no for-loops)

- `free(first);`
- `free(second);`
- `free(multiply);`

Comment: +1: Please, can you show where add free() to complete your sample?

Comment: @user2079986 Not sure which errors you were getting, but changed `for (int i` to `for (i` which fixes some errors.

Comment: I am getting warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âmallocâ but I am not able to get the input via text file , I used ./cprograma.out < input.txt

Comment: @user2079986 My Linux knowledge is somewhat limited, but after a quick Google search, looks like `cat input.txt | cprograma.out` might work.

Comment: @user2079986 I think `#include <stdlib.h>` will remove your warning.

Comment: Ya that warning was removed but I am still unable to get input from txt file. do I need to run loop which would determine EOF of my file

Comment: @user2079986 1) Are there more than 1 sets of arrays in the file? Then you'll need to loop through. How to check for EOF I'm not sure about. If the issue is just reading 1, it may be helpful to just echo what you read from standard input using `printf` and see if anything prints out. 2) This is really a completely different question (which I can't really help you with much). There should be more than enough similar questions online, but if you can find a solution, it should be posted as a *separate* question (with a minimum test case).

Comment: I am getting correct result while inputting from keyboard but